# windows rdp active x control does not show anything

Tags: c#, rdp

I try to use the Remote Desktop ActiveX control in a WinForm app.  I was following the example given on codeproject (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET).
The sample fails to work.  In the connect button handler I get an invalid cast exception when I execute `IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdp.GetOcx();`
Other references found on Google mention to use any of the `AdvancedSettings`members of the ActiveX control instance and set the `ClearTextPassword` property on it.  I was not able to find such a property anywhere.  I am out of ideas on how to get that control to work.

Does anyone have a current example of how to open a remote desctop sessioin with the RDP ActiveX control?

Comment: that post was written in 2009, that could be tested on a lower version of Windows than yours. When you choose items to the Toolbox, there are different versions of the same "Microsoft RDP client control" (version 2 to 11 on mine) available, try to choose the highest version.

Comment: I did.  Highest version was 9 (Windows 7).

Answer (score 2):

I also have some remote servers to look after, after some hard time I manage to make it work, HTH.

Note that Network Level Authentication (NLA) is configured for Remote Desktop session to these servers, that is why I need to set the **EnableCredSspSupport** property. If leave this property unset, the RDP control does not show anything, and there seems to be no error either.

```
rdp.Server = "";
rdp.UserName = "";
rdp.AdvancedSettings9.ClearTextPassword="";
rdp.AdvancedSettings9.EnableCredSspSupport = true;
rdp.Connect();
```

Comment: The problem I have is, that I am not able to see the ´rdp.AdvancedSettings9.ClearTextPassword´property.  It does not exist on ´AdvancedSettings9´, at least for the control I could find on my Windows 7 machine.

Comment: What is the type of the Control? Is it AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting? (The naming is a mess.)

Comment: Yes, it is AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent several hours to figure out what is wrong with ActiveX... This is an expected behavior of RDP ActiveX - show nothing until the connection is successfully established. In my case I've subscribed on `AxMsRdpClient10NotSafeForScripting::OnDisconnect` event and receive the `516` disconnection error. And it turned out that the RDP was disabled on the agent machine... You can quick check the RDP connection using `mstsc.exe` to see the errors. In my case it works well after enabling the RDP on the agent machine.